# Azure App Service deployment fails with: Platform 'java' version '11.0.8' is unsupported

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

We have an azure app service which contains a PHP 5.6 app

We use local git to deploy to that app using git remotes.

The command we use is
`git push remote-name HEAD:master`

This is the entire message that appears in the git bash dialog:

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 382 bytes | 127.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Checking connectivity: 4, done.
remote: Deploy Async
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: ............
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '3731bff201'.
remote: Repository path is /home/site/repository
remote: Running oryx build...
remote: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
remote: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
remote:
remote: Oryx Version: 0.2.20200917.1, Commit: 59deb778658a124cb74ea8e2c8f39fa87abcc9d9, ReleaseTagName: 20200917.1
remote:
remote: Build Operation ID: |A+SucU1uce4=.5b60ab5f_
remote: Repository Commit : 3731bff20118d7747e4e6d99c795f058fc469a64
remote:
remote: Detecting platforms...
remote: .....................................................................
remote: Error: Platform 'java' version '11.0.8' is unsupported. Supported versions:
remote: Deployment Logs : 'xxxx'
To yyyy
   4595f2cc5..3731bff20  HEAD -> master
```

(I've replaced a few urls with xxxx and yyyy)

I believe the key here is: Platform 'java' version '11.0.8' is unsupported

I just don't know where that can be fixed.

I've tried searching for answers but all I found was a suggestion to set this value to false:
`SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT= FALSE`

I've tried deploying with other apps and I get the same issue.

Comment: Not get your latest information, if the following answer is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Oryx source, the java detector seems to be triggering as your project contains files with either `.java` or `.jsp` extensions.

This could potentially be because of a node module you are using that contains java files.

**Azure DevOps**

You can override this by configuring **Runtime Stack** property in your Azure App Service deploy step in Azure DevOps to the version of Node you require.

[image]

**Azure - Local Git/Kudo**

In your project, install the kuduscript tool (`npm install kuduscript -g`) and run `kuduscript -y --node` to create a custom deployment script, the commit the new files and your deployment should succeed. For more on creating a custom deployment script for more complicated deployments see [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script).

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/a6b4b3d3a7e255432c33561f195be8776748f5b2/src/Detector/Java/JavaDetector.cs)